# What to do after OP askes a question and then immediately realises its (trivial) answer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

After 1hr thinking in a problem, I gave up, and then I asked [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2385830/gaussian-curvature-from-revolution-surface-where-is-wrong) on math SE. Then, 1 minute after posting it, I realized the answer. Did that already happen to you? What should one do in this situation? Should one delete the question? Or let it for others?

In particular, since this question of mine is of the type "please spot my mistake" I don't think it is useful for other people, and I guess I should have deleted it. I would like to know what to do in such cases.

With that in mind, extending from the boundaries of my question, and going to to all possible questions, I ask: When exactly one should delete a question immediately after its posted because one found the answer? Always? Never? Depends on the question? Which types of questions should be deleted?

Comment: A very similar Question was asked not long ago: [Formulating the problem helps solving it --> self-answer or delete question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26564/formulating-the-problem-helps-solving-it-self-answer-or-delete-question)

Comment: I suggest deleting it if it's posted in 1,2 minutes otherwise keep it open, and mention either in a comment or in a edit that you found the answer after posting but would appreciate if there are more elegant answers.

Comment: Keep in mind that *you can answer your own question*.

Comment: Better yet, self answer, which allows us to provide feedback on what we think of your solution as well as leaving the question open so you may see other solutions other than your own.

Comment: Well, somebody might be in the process of writing an answer - they might not like if the question is deleted. In fact, there were some complaints about this in the past, for example: [Sometimes, deleting a question shouldn't be immediate?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22812) or [On deleting vs. closing duplicate questions.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3338)